# Java print multiple lines after reading multiple lines

Tags: java, loops, input, line

(It's my homework task. So I can't make any changes to the task like changing the rules of input.)

I need to calculate

```
a^m mod n
```

and print out the result. (I've already figured out how to code the calculation.)

But the question said there'll be multiple lines of input:

```
IN:

12 5 47
2 4 89
29 5 54
```

and need to print all the results together after reading all the lines of input. (You can't print the results right after one line of input.)

```
OUT:

14
16
5
```

The code I've tried so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class mod {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 0;
        while (input.hasNextLine()){
            count++;
        }
        int[] array = new int[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i ++){  
            int a = input.nextInt();
            int m = input.nextInt();
            int n = input.nextInt();
            int result = (int)((Math.pow(a, m)) % n);
            array[i] = result;
        }
        for (int x : array){
             System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to count the lines of input and build an array of that size to store the results.

But it seems my code fail to detect the end of input and keep looping.

Comment: You need to, in your first loop, read each line and perform the calculation on that line and output the result, otherwise, you need to close and reopen the file before trying to read it again

Comment: Check my answer and explanation.

Comment: How do you know when the user is done inputting?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks! but the task ask me to only output the result after reading all lines.

Comment: @D M  yes that's my question. I think the user done inputting by pressing the "enter" key. but I'm not sure how to detect that.

Comment: @V.Liang Then you need to close the file and re-open after you've counted the number of lines and before you start reading it again - You've read to the end of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the user's input in the initial loop with a `List<String>`, I would suggest terminating the loop on an empty `String` and only adding lines that match the three numbers separated by whitespace characters. Also, I would print the result in the second loop. Then you don't need a result `array`. I would also *prefer* formatted io (i.e. `System.out.printf`). Like,

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = input.nextLine();
    if (line.isEmpty()) {
        break;
    } else if (line.matches("\\d+\\s+\\d+\\s+\\d+")) {
        lines.add(line);
    }
}
int count = lines.size();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    String[] tokens = lines.get(i).split("\\s+");
    int a = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]), m = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]), 
            n = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
    int result = (int) ((Math.pow(a, m)) % n);
    System.out.printf("(%d ^ %d) %% %d = %d%n", a, m, n, result);
}
```

I tested with your provided input,

```
12 5 47
2 4 89
29 5 54

(12 ^ 5) % 47 = 14
(2 ^ 4) % 89 = 16
(29 ^ 5) % 54 = 5
```